# iOS 10 access to camera and photos

Tags: cordova, ios10, privacy, inappbrowser, info.plist

I'm building an hybrid app using Ionic and inAppBrowser (branch called ThemeableBrowser). My problem is that I cannot access the camera inside any of the apps that I open using inAppBrowser. I have changed config.xml and added

```
<config-file parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Godkänner du att appen får tillgång till din kamera?</string>
</config-file>
<config-file parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist">
    <string>Godkänner du att appen får tillgång till ditt fotobibliotek?</string>
</config-file>
```

but it is still not working. All I can find while googling is that I need to add the above two things to the config.xml, but it is not working for me on iOS 10. On iOS 9 it's working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the runtime permission dialogs being displayed (which requests access to Camera/Photos)?

Comment: @DaveAlden no, the are not. The app dies before the dialog is shown

Comment: How are you applying the `<config-file>` blocks in your `config.xml` to your `.plist` file? Cordova does not do this by default (only for the `plugin.xml` of plugins) so you need something like [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) to apply the changes to the plist. You can check if your plist actually contains the usage description messages your are expecting: `platforms/ios/ProjectName/ProjectName-Info.plist`